# Is it possible to check nested field is exist or null in $project using $ifNull in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I would like to check a nested field is exist or null. if exist then return that value otherwise return default value for that field. need to use `.aggregate` because I need to perform some aggregate operation also.

say my doc is like:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("581a18d41b6c5c752f11c87a"),
    "email": "aa@gmail.com",
    "name" : "xxxxxx",
    "memberType" : "Guest",
    "name" : "M1",
    "inviter": {
      "status": 'active'
    }
},

{
"_id" : ObjectId("581a18d41b6c5c752f11c87b"),
    //....
    "name" : "M2",
    "inviter": {
    }
}
```

and I would like to get data like

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("581a18d41b6c5c752f11c87a"),
    "data": ["M1","active"]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("581a18d41b6c5c752f11c87b"),
    "data": ["M2","inactive"]
}
```

I tried:

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([
      {$match:{"email" :{$ne:'bb@gmail.com'}}},
      {$sort:{_id:1}},
      {$project:{
          "_id" : "$_id",
          "data":
             ["$name",
              { "$inviter.status":{$ifNull: [ "$inviter.status", 'inactive'] }},
             ]
       }}
   ])
```

but got error

> "errmsg" : "invalid operator
>   '$inviter.status'",

is it possible check nested field using `$ifNull` or how can I solved this?

Comment: Project is basically to specify the inclusion of a field. You give it in the form of fieldname : $ literal. In your example, it should be something  { "status":{$ifNull: [ "$inviter.status", 'inactive'] }},

Answer (score 2, accepted):

was my bad. should be `{$ifNull: [ "$inviter.status", 'inactive'] }` instead of `{ "$inviter.status":{$ifNull: [ "$inviter.status", 'inactive'] }}`

solved like:

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([
      {$match:{"email" :{$ne:'bb@gmail.com'}}},
      {$sort:{_id:1}},
      {$project:{
          "_id" : "$_id",
          "data":
             ["$name",
              {$ifNull: [ "$inviter.status", 'inactive'] },
             ]
       }}
   ])
```